# plotly python change y-axis values ​to your own

Tags: python-3.x, plotly, plotly-python

A graph of random values ​​is plotted. It is necessary to change the values ​​of the Y axis to others.

```
xg = np.random.rand(100, 1200)
fig = px.imshow(xg, aspect="auto",color_continuous_scale='ice')
fig.show()
```

values ​​to be changed

```
y1=np.arange(100)*0.5
y2=np.arange(100)*5
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- 100 ticks on the yaxis is too many!  Have gone with 10
- simple case of defining where you want ticks in the range of values (100) and text you want to display again domain value https://plotly.com/python/tick-formatting/#tickmode--array
- the multiplications are equivalent to your requirements,  just generating arrays of appropriate length (ten ticks)

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px

xg = np.random.rand(100, 1200)
fig = px.imshow(xg, aspect="auto",color_continuous_scale='ice')

# y1
fig.update_layout(yaxis={"tickmode":"array","tickvals":np.arange(10)*10, "ticktext":np.arange(10)*5}).show()
# y2
fig.update_layout(yaxis={"tickmode":"array","tickvals":np.arange(10)*10, "ticktext":np.arange(10)*50}).show()
```

#### supplementary - show both y-axis

- as per comment you can use documented approach https://plotly.com/python/multiple-axes/#multiple-axes
- you do require a trace per axis hence creation of two traces and modification of second trace to use **y2**
- setting second trace to `"visible":False` does not work.  So there are two identical traces on top of each other

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px

xg = np.random.rand(100, 1200)
fig = px.imshow(xg, aspect="auto", color_continuous_scale="ice").add_traces(
    px.imshow(xg, aspect="auto", color_continuous_scale="ice")
    .update_traces(yaxis="y2")
    .data
)

fig.update_layout(
    xaxis={"domain": [0.05, 1]},
    yaxis={
        "tickmode": "array",
        "tickvals": np.arange(10) * 10,
        "ticktext": np.arange(10) * 50,
    },
    yaxis2={
        "tickmode": "array",
        "tickvals": np.arange(10) * 10,
        "ticktext": np.arange(10) * 5,
        "anchor": "free",
        "position": 0,
        "autorange": "reversed",
    },
).show()
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to make two Y-axes appear on one chart at once?

Comment: yes it's documented: https://plotly.com/python/multiple-axes/#multiple-axes.  You will require a trace per y-axis

Comment: 100 ticks is not pretty, but I need the honesty of my data. Can you do that the data would be hidden, but shown on the graph itself?

Comment: I've inserted additional code in answer.  As I noted this is fully explained in plotly documentation